In my magento 2.4.6, The product sorting for categories is not working. Like price high to low and low to high and sort filter is not working
In my magento 2.4.6, The product sorting for categories is not working. Like price high to low and low to high and sort filter is not working . Rest all other filters are working. When selecting sorting - low to high the url is getting updated but the products are not getting updated

can you share any URL with me? Also do you have installed any 3rd party module in your project

Hello, I resolved the issue. There was some issue in code in listProduct.php file
